# Combining Enum Value using Bitmask

Tags: c++, c, enums, bitmask

I understand it's possible to use bitmasks in enum values, but I don't know how to create it.

I have a simple enum :

```
enum State
{
    minimizing = 0,
    maximizing,

    minimized,
    maximized
};
```

A state is always `State.minimized` or `State.maximized`, and can have additional state on resize. So something can be Maximized and minimizing

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am going to assume that `myState` has the type of your `enum State`.

The traditional use of `enum` is to create the constant values that a variable of this type can take. You wish to set you variable `myState` to a **combination** of the values defined in the `enum`.

The `enum` defines 1, 2, 4, and 8 as valid values, yet you want to be able to set the variable to 4 | 2 = 6. While C uses your implementation-defined `int` type for all `enum`, it is not the case in C++. `myState = 6` is not valid in C++. Actually, `myState = 4` is not either valid in C++, you need to cast explicitly or use one of the constant names of the `enum`.

Although possible in C, it is not good practice to set `myState` to a value that is not defined by its type (for example to 6).

In your case, a solution that seems consequent would be:

```
typedef enum {
    OTHER,
    MINIMIZED,
    MAXIMIZED
} win_size_t;

typedef struct {
    win_size_t current;
    win_size_t next;
} state_t;

state_t myState;
```

That way, you can write to the fields `current` and `next` undependently.

If you still want to have bit fields, you can set the size of the elements of your struct in bits. It is kind of dangerous though, the implementation of bit fields depend on your compiler. I am not even sure if compilers would accept to have an enum type in a bit field (should be ok in C, since `enum`s are `int`).

```
typedef struct {
    win_size_t current : 2;  // not tested
    win_size_t next : 2;
} state_t;
```

The previous given solutions are valid of course. My point is that if your variable `myState` has your `enum State` as type, it should only use the members of the `enum` for its values, not a combination.

Maybe `myState` has another type, what do I know.

---

If `myState` is not of the `enum State` type, then you may use the constants defined in your `enum` in combination.

```
enum State {
    MINIMIZING = (1u << 0),
    MAXIMIZING = (1u << 1),
    MINIMIZED  = (1u << 2),
    MAXIMIZED  = (1u << 3),
};

unsigned int myState = 0;

myState |= MAXIMIZED;  // sets that bit
myState &= ~MAXIMIZED; // resets that bit
```

This allows you to do two things in one assignment:

```
myState = MAXIMIZED | MINIMIZING;
```

But also things you are not likely to want:

```
myState = MAXIMIZED | MINIMIZED;  // does that make sense?
```

Comment: thanks ! I went for option #1. Indeed that makes no sens that `MAXIMIZED | MINIMIZED` is possible, and for it's better for readability to have two enums.

Comment: Please note, that restricting enumerations to bit-fileds are undefined behavior and the result depends on the compiler. Also please correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: @DavidTóth You seem to be correct, thanks for this! https://stackoverflow.com/a/33590935/108802

Answer (score 16):

Use a different bit for every value in your enumeration, such as:

```
enum State 
{
  minimizing = 0x01, // 00000001
  maximizing = 0x02, // 00000010
  minimized  = 0x04, // 00000100
  maximized  = 0x08  // 00001000
}:
```

Then, you can combine multiple values with bitwise or (`minimizing | maximized`) and test for values with bitwise and (`bool is_minimized = (flags & minimized);`).

Comment: Question of taste, but I prefer: `(1u << 0)`, `(1u << 1)`, `(1u << 2)`, `(1u << 3)`. It is more clear which bit you mean.

Comment: Why define the values in hex notation? `minimizing = 1` works too

Comment: @NatanYellin: it does, but if you are to add one more state and you are using decimal, you'd have to write 16. Say that you the want to set two bits, bit 4 and bit 1. The result is 18 in decimal, which is less readable than 0x12 (if this is not obvious, try to identify what bits are set in 2398 decimal. Much easier if you have the equivalent 0x95E). If you are interested in which bits are set, hexadecimal is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this in VS2012, the optimizer seems to correctly combine bits without any need for assistance if you're using bitfields.

```
struct BITS { int x: 1; int y:1; };
```

then

```
BITS b;
b.x = b.y = 1;
```

Sets both bits with one instruction.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this effect by specifying all fields in the enum and increased in powers of two to get the bitmask effect.  For example, in your case:

```
enum State
{
    minimizing = 1,
    maximizing = 2,

    minimized = 4,
    maximized = 8
};
```

So you can then have your combinations of `(State.maximized | State.minimizing)`.  However this won't apply the restriction of only being `State.maximized` or `State.minimized`.  If you want to do that you could convert them to a single bit, but I imagine in this example you would want to be able to have a case where it is neither maximized nor minimized.

Comment: which is usually written using shifts

Comment: but then, how can I use it ? Like i have : `myState = minimized; if (isMaximizing) { myState = maximizing }` I want to set the maximizing state, without loosing the minimized state

Comment: Then you can use `myState |= maximizing;`. This sets the bit you're interesting in without touching the other bits. For zeroing, use `myState &= ~maximizing;`. Be careful when doing comparisons, `myState == minimized` won't work, you'd need `(myState & minimized) == minimized` (or `!= 0`). If I were you, I'd consider a struct with one field as "current state" and another for "next state".

Comment: Note that while the `enum State` defines some constants, it does not define a combination of them. If `myState` is minimized and maximizing, the resulting value is `0x02 | 0x04`, that is `0x06`. Not a value defined by your enum.