# Are enums as bitfields implementation-defined types?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99

I'm trying to better understand the C99 standard but now I'm confused about using enums as bitfields in structs and if they are treated as int or as implementation-defined type. When looking up in the final draft for C99, I found 6.7.2.1 para. 4

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of  **_Bool**, **signed int**, **unsigned int**, or some other implementation-defined type.

and 6.7.2.2 para. 4

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with **char**, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration. ...

So I tried with this simple source code

```
enum e {
    E0, E1
};

struct s {
    enum e bitfield : 4;
};
```

I can compile this without warnings with gcc-5.0 and clang-3.5 using `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` but I get the following warning with gcc-4.8

```
warning: type of bit-field 'bitfield' is a GCC extension
```

Here start the confusion. Are enums as bitfields treated as int or implemenation-defined type? Is this a bug in GCC-4.8 or did they change their interpretation of the standard? And is it safe to use this with other C99-compiler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning when using bitfield with unsigned char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906238/warning-when-using-bitfield-with-unsigned-char)

Comment: @Rhymoid I'm not sure if this is really a duplicate. AFAIK are unsigned char a subtype of unsigned int whereas enum can be equivalent to int. It can also be that I misinterpret the "compatible with [...] integer type" in 6.7.2.2 para. 4.

Comment: The first quote means that it's implementation-defined which other types are allowed  to be used as bitfields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are enums as bitfields implementation-defined types?

Yes.

What you're seeing is a change in the implementation-defined behavior of gcc.

As it says in the section of the standard you quoted, a bit field must be of type `_Bool`, `int`, `unsigned int`, *or* some implementation-defined type.

A `enum` type is compatible with some integer type. Experiment and a look at the gcc manual shows that for gcc, your `enum e` is compatible with `unsigned int`. But the standard doesn't permit a bit field to be of a type *compatible* with `unsigned int`. It actually has to be of type `unsigned int` (compatible types are not necessarily the same type). *Except* that it can also be of some other implementation-defined type.

According to the [manual for gcc 4.8.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html):

> - *Allowable bit-field types other than `_Bool`, `signed int`, and `unsigned int` (C99 6.7.2.1).*
>
> No other types are permitted in strictly conforming mode.

According to the manual for gcc-5.2.0:

> - *Allowable bit-field types other than `_Bool`, `signed int`, and `unsigned int` (C99 and C11 6.7.2.1).*
>
> Other integer types, such as `long int`, and enumerated types are permitted even in strictly conforming mode.

So what you're seeing is a change in the behavior of gcc, allowing more types for bit fields even in "strictly conforming mode". This is not a change in gcc's interpretation of the standard; both behaviors are permitted.

Using `enum`s as bit fields is not portable. A conforming C compiler may or may not support them. (I personally would have preferred it if gcc had kept the ability to get a warning for this.)

Answer (score 0):

It may be safe, but don't do it.  You're violating an implied design-by-contract.  Sort of.  You mentioned the construct, but didn't mention how you really wanted to use it.  There may be a cleaner way.

If you have:

```
typedef enum {
    E0, E1, E2
} myenum_t;

myenum_t val;
```

Now, if you have various switch statements, such as:

```
switch (val) {
case E0:
    ...
    break;
case E1:
    ...
    break;
case E2:
    ...
    break;
}
```

They will be checked at compile time to ensure your `switch` covered all the cases.  If you then add an `E3` to your enum definition, the compiler will flag the `switch` statements as missing `E3`.  This is useful.

If you start bit diddling your enum value, you may have to change your `switch` to:

```
switch (val) {
case E0:
    ...
    break;
case E1:
    ...
    break;
case E2:
    ...
    break;
default:
    ...
    break;
}
```

Now, if you add `E3` to your enum, the compiler *won't* flag your `switch` for the missing `case` because it assumes `default` will handle it.  Maybe not what you want.

Adding the `default` is usually there to debug errant enum values.

However, if you had:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int mask:8;
    unsigned int enval:8;
    unsigned int ident:8;
    unsigned int other:8;
} mybit_t;

mybit_t bval;
```

Using the following:

```
switch ((myenum_t) bval.enval) {
    ...
}
```

Is possibly a bit cleaner and maybe closer to what you really hope to achieve.

The "implied contract" is that [in this context] enums are intended to be a set of whole numbers.  Note that you can also have:

```
typedef enum {
    M0 = 1 << E0, M1 = 1 << E1, M2 = 1 << E2
} mymask_t;
```

And, it's perfectly fine to do something like: `bval.mask |= M2;`.  Leave the bitfield slicing and dicing to `int` where you can control the size [sort of].  There's no advantage to trying to apply a semi-non-portable extension when using the standard stuff works just fine.