# cannot initialize a variable of type 'designFlags' with an rvalue of type 'int'

Tags: c++, enums, bitwise-operators, flags

i am trying to create an enum flag that would see if a certain thing was bold and italic, but i am getting compilation error:
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'designFlags' with an rvalue of type 'int'
    designFlags myDesign = BOLD | UNDERLINE;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum designFlags {
    BOLD = 1,
    ITALICS = 2,
    UNDERLINE = 4
};

int main() 
{
    designFlags myDesign = BOLD | UNDERLINE; 

        //    00000001
        //  | 00000100
        //  ___________
        //    00000101

    cout << myDesign;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *What* compilation error? Please copy and paste it here to make it [mcve].

Comment: `BOLD | UNDERLINE` is not necessarily a valid `designFlags` value. Why not make `myDesign` an `int` instead?

Comment: `designFlags` is a combination of flags, so it should be declared as an int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining Enum Value using Bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920783/combining-enum-value-using-bitmask)

Comment: @alterigel for an un-scoped enum, the valid values are the range of values of the representable enumerators. The enumerators require 3 bits to represent, so any 3 bit value is valid - regardless of whether they are explicitly named as enum values. `BOLD | UNDERLINE` is definitely valid.

Comment: @jspcal values not explicitly present in a enum are still valid enum values if they are within the representable range of the enum as defined by the standard (old school enums and scoped enums differ slightly). Using `int` is *not* required.

Comment: Perhaps cheating, but: `auto myDesign = BOLD | UNDERLINE;`

Comment: @JesperJuhl You can't *automatically convert* `int` to an `enum`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard prevents you from performing an implicit cast from `int` to `enum` (Note: implicit conversion from `enum` to `int` is allowed).

However, you can perform an static cast instead:

```
designFlags myDesign = static_cast<designFlags>(BOLD | UNDERLINE);
cout << myDesign; // prints 5
```

Have in mind that it is most like that the resulting value is not one of the values specifies in `designFlags`. This is usually a common practice, but you have to rely to bit-wise operations to perform comparisons:

For example:

```
// wrong
if (myDesign == BOLD)

// ok (most of the time)
if (myDesign & BOLD)

// always ok
if ((myDesign & BOLD) == BOLD)
```

**Update: Why is `myDesign & BOLD` ok most of the time?**

When you use flags, the values must be powers of two: 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. Therefore, every possible value has only one bit set, and this bit is different for each one.

Then, when you do `myDesign & BOLD`, you are testing for one specific bit, and just that. If the bit is set, the result will be non-zero (bitwise AND). If the bit it not set, the result will be zero.

When it can go wrong? Well, if you use flags that are not a power of two, each individual value will have more than one bit set, making it difficult to perform these checks.

For instance, suppose you have this definition:

```
enum designFlags {
    BOLD = 2,
    ITALICS = 4,
    UNDERLINE = 6
};
```

And then you set your design to `UNDERLINE`:

```
myDesign = UNDERLINE
```

What is the result of the following tests?

```
myDesign & BOLD
myDesign & ITALICS
```

It will be non-zero for both of them, surely an undesired behavior.

Of course you can do the following:

```
if ((myDesign & BOLD) == BOLD) {
    ...
```

but i rather use flags with only one bit set.

Comment: why is ```myDesign & BOLD``` ok most of the time? what would be the case when it's wrong?

Comment: @Andrii I updated my answer with some comments, hope it helps!

Comment: Ah didn't consider multi-bit flags, thank you!